# I think I have a cryptomining virus, vmmem

Tags: virus, virus-removal

My computer (Win10) was running slow and hot, and I noticed that a process called vmmem was using 85-99% of my CPU. I became concerned when I tried to shut down the process from Task Manager, and it said I didn't have permission (I was in an Administrator profile). I ran `wsl --shutdown` in the command line, and shut down my computer. Now, my CPU is running at a more normal level, but I'm concerned that I have a virus on my computer. Although I'm no security expert, I know how to code, and I'm not afraid of doing hard work to get to the bottom of this issue.  How should I proceed, and ensure I don't have a virus(es)?
[image: From Task Manager]

Comment: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20180717-00/?p=99265 This is *not* necessarily malware.

Comment: Did you look up what this process was? This is very simple to look up and to see why it eats CPU.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is based on a faulty premise and is easy to look up.

Comment: would move this to SuperUser?

Answer (score 2):

This **vmmem** is not a virus. It is a process which runs when you use docker (wsl) in Windows computer.
It is in my computer too.
[image]

You can check this microsoft document for configuring wsl's resource usage
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/wsl/wsl-config